# How to move caret to console in pycharm?

Tags: python, console, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to have a keyboard shortcut to move the caret from editor to console and back in pycharm? I can switch the focus between editor and console using CTRL+TAB, but that doesn't allow me to start typing in the console unless I click in it.

I am using the linux community distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on MacOS and PyCharm 2018.2. Doing `Ctrl+Tab+P` opens up console and focuses on it so I can immediately start typing.

Update: You can also set your own key map: `Tool Windows/Python Console`. Hitting `Esc` will focus you back on the editor window.

Comment: It does not work for me. Can you please let me know what is it called in the keymap settings? Maybe I need to set it up.

Comment: @ManishGoel That is weird - I just keep the Switcher open with Ctrl+Tab being pressed and hit `P` shortcut for the python console. If that doesn't work for you you can set up a KeyMap. It's called `Tool Windows/Python Console`. (Hit `Esc` to focus back on the editor)

Comment: Yups.. I restarted pycharm and it worked. Don't know what happened. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to hit the `TAB` key once (potentially twice) after you move into the Python Console (via whatever shortcut you specify in the keymap).

Answer (score 0):

I think it also depends on whether the Python Console is docked - looks like it doesn't work if the Console is in another Window. So my current setup is having the Console docked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alt + 4` or `Alt + 5` where the digit is the window number. And then to refocus back to the edit you press `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years later but i found my self in this situations, i believe the other answers are good enough for some but they lack some important information or at least i didn't found it.

You need to look for the term *Python or debug console* under *tools* if you want to focus to the console with the caret at it, add a keymap value for that (in my case i added ALT+2), do **NOT** use the *python console* under tool windows, for that it will focus on the python console but not the caret at it.

*(done with pycharm 2020.1.1 in a ubuntu 20.04 lts machine)*

[image: focus caret on python console pycharm]

[image: pycharm professional edition 2020.1.1]